# While loop python, s=s+1

Tags: python, while-loop

I was trying to make a program that would ask for 2 values, s and n.
It would then print s*n for s>0 until it reaches s.
For example we enter 5 for s and 3 for n
The output should be:

```
 1 * 3 = 3
 2 * 3 = 6
 3 * 3 = 9
 4 * 3 = 12
 5 * 3 = 15
```

I know that the following code is completely wrong as " s * n =" is a string. But I don't know how else to do it.

```
 s = int(input("Enter a number: "))
 n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
 while s>0:
 s = s+1
 print("s * n =", s*n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
s = int(input("Enter a number: "))
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
index = 0

while index < s:
    index = index + 1
    print("{} * {} = {}" .format(index, s, index * s))
```

Comment: if user set 5 for s and 3 for n, your code outputs: 1*5=5 2*5=10 3*5=15, that does not meet @jake 's need.

Comment: You are right, was a mistake with the variable name. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `s` equals `5`, if `s>0` you will execute while loop, but you always increase `s`, that means while loop never stop.

I think you can try:

```
s = int(input("Enter a number: "))
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

i = 0
while i < s:
    i += 1
    print("%d * %d = %d" % (i, n, i*n))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's rarely a reason to increment a counter in Python.  If iterating over a list, use `for object in objects:`.  If you need the index, use `for index,object in enumerate(objects)`.  In your case, there is `range`:

```
s = int(input("Enter a number: "))
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for i in range(1,s+1):
    print('{} * {} = {}'.format(i,n,i*n))
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 3
1 * 3 = 3
2 * 3 = 6
3 * 3 = 9
4 * 3 = 12
5 * 3 = 15
```

Note that `range(a)` produces `0` through `a-1` and `range(a,b)` produces `a` through `b-1`.

`.format` is a powerful way to construct strings from parameters.

References:

[range](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#range)
[format](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)
[Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)